# Remove a database column during Heroku release without raising exceptions

Tags: heroku, database-migration

I'm trying to understand Heroku's release phase. As far as I can tell, Heroku will serve requests from the existing dynos during the release phase. Is that correct?

Which means that if I remove a column from the database during the release phase, then the existing dynos will be serving requests that use the database that has this column removed. It is only when the release phase finally finishes (which could take a moment if I'm running other things besides migrations in the release tasks) that the new dynos with the new code will be swapped into serving requests.

During the time it takes the release phase to finish and the new code being swapped into place, there will be exceptions raised (I use Python) by code that is trying to access the removed column.

Does that make sense, and is my understanding correct?

So to avoid exceptions being raised, I guess it is best to deploy twice. Once to remove code that accesses the database column to be removed, and a second time to remove the column. Is this a strategy that people use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about release phase: the behaviour you describe is part of [preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot), which you have to activate for your application. Otherwise Heroku will stop the old dynos before booting the new ones.

About dropping the column: 
Yes, since the routers point to the old dynos while release phase is running, errors will happen.

The strategy here is exactly what you proposed, do a first deploy removing the code, then a second one removing the column.

Keep in mind that some database operations also lock the whole table for some time, where reads and writes to the whole table have to wait (DROP COLUMN I believe also gets a full table lock). Also for example adding a column with a default on a bigger table takes quite much time.